# Manage stock via JS

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I am creating a product order form with JS and i was wondering if it is possible to hide a product/checkbox once the stock has finished ? I have the following HTML.

```
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E33" value="33" stock="20"/> Product A 
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E34" value="33" stock="6"/> Product B
<input class="iput" type="checkbox" name="E66" value="33" stock="7"/> Product C
```

Lets say the 6 people have chosen product B while filling out the form, is possible to prevent the 7th user from being able to select product B as its stock will be finished by the time the 7th user arrives at the form ?

Comment: You would need to set up websockets and sent real time updates to each user. You couldn't rely on page loads alone unless traffic is low. One user might open page and immediately start submitting while another might spend an hour reading, thinking, cooking dinner before submitting

Comment: Websockets would 99% certainly be overkill. After all, the transaction is eventually carried out server-side; if the product happens to have run out meanwhile, the user can be redirected back to the form to try again.

Comment: Hmm i see ... But i was wondering was is possible via JS to automatically decrease the value of stock by 1 after a user has selected that checkbox and hit the submit button ?

Comment: That would be handled server side when you process the submit and update database